# Rewrite concat function in es6

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a simple function which I am trying to rewrite in es6 but I am not getting it

Where arr1 and arr2 are multidimensional arrays of different widths i.e. arr1[0].length != arr2[0].length
but do have the same lengths

```
function conatArrAsColumns(arr1, arr2) {
  
//This works
  var result = arr1.map(function(row, i){
  return row.concat(arr2[i]);
  });
  
  
//This works
  var result = arr1.map((row, i) => {
  return row.concat(arr2[i]);
  });
  
  
 //This does not work
  var result = arr1.map((row) => {
  return row.concat(arr2);
  });
  

//This does not work
  var result = arr1.map(row => row.concat(arr2)));

  return result
}
```

I am trying to get this to work

`var result = arr1.map(row => row.concat(arr2)));`

Thank you for any assistance with this

Comment: Your parentheses are not balanced.

Comment: The ones that don’t work are missing the index. Why did you remove it?

Comment: this not working either ```var result = arr1.map((row, i) => row.concat(arr2([i])));``` I get `arr2` is not a function

Comment: where are the parentheses not balanced here? ```var result = arr1.map((row) => {
  return row.concat(arr2);
  });```

Comment: `var result = arr1.map(row => row.concat(arr2)));` two opening brackets, three closing brackets

Comment: Also, the last two that don't work - you're concatenating the whole of `arr2` to each row in `arr1`, instead of using `arr2[i]` like the first two pieces of code.

Comment: I don't why this was so difficult for me to get!! `var result = arr1.map((row,i) => row.concat(arr2[i]))` works.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempts that "work" all use the index, whereas the ones that don't "work" do not. Your last example that you are "trying to get this to work", is correct - you're just missing the index:

```
var result = arr1.map((row, i) => row.concat(arr2[i]));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right, and you want to merge two arrays in one, you can use spread-operator:

```js
function conatArrAsColumns(arr1, arr2) {
  const arr3 = [...arr1, arr2]
  return arr3
  }

console.log(conatArrAsColumns([1,2,[1,2],3], [4,5,6,7,[8,9],10,11]))
//will return [1,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

Comment: Oh, that's how you do that with the spread operator. Thank you Vic